# how to display phython output in web app?

Tags: python, flask

I cannot find a way to output my result in a Flask web-app.

I get this error message:

```
<function listen.<locals>.myoutput at 0x000001FF251E8CA0>
```

#### Code

```py
from flask import Flask
import pyaudio
import wave
import asyncio
from ShazamAPI import Shazam
from flask import render_template,request,redirect

app =Flask(_name_)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',pageTitle='Discover Tunes')

@app.route('/listen', methods=['POST','GET'])
def listen():
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=request.form
        FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
        CHANNELS = 2
        RATE = 44100
        CHUNK = 1024
        RECORD_SECONDS = 10
        WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "record.wav"
         
        audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
         
        # start Recording
        stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
        print ("recording sample...")
        frames = []
         
        for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
            data = stream.read(CHUNK)
            frames.append(data)
        print ("finished recording")
         
         
        # stop Recording
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
         
        waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
        waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        waveFile.close()


        mp3_file_content_to_recognize = open('record.WAV', 'rb').read()
        shazam = Shazam(mp3_file_content_to_recognize)
        recognize_generator =shazam.recognizeSong()
        while request.is_json:
            return (recognize_generator)

    def myoutput():
        global myoutput
        myoutput=recognize_generator["title"]
        print(myoutput)
        return myoutput


return render_template('index.html',display=myoutput, pageTitle='Discover Tunes')

return redirect("/")


if _name=='main_':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error message. You're failing to call your `myoutput` function here:

```
return render_template('index.html',display=myoutput, pageTitle='Discover Tunes')
```

You're missing the parentheses that would actually cause your function to execute, so Python is instead giving you a textual representation of the function. (Functions are values like any other, so you can store them in variables, pass them as arguments to other functions, and so on. The latter is what you're accidentally doing here.)

Just add the parentheses:

```
return render_template('index.html',display=myoutput(), pageTitle='Discover Tunes')
```